# Foreign accent handling in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populating my sql tables using PHP code. For words with accent like ('pépite') , they are inserted as 'pÃ©pite'. Some extra characters are inserted in my string.
Here is my code:

```
$word = 'pépite';
$query = "Insert into [Tracker].[dbo].[Demo] values ('".$word."')";
sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
echo $word;
// output : pÃ©pite
```

I have tried with utf8_decode as well. But this gives some abstract output.

Comment: You need to take care that _all_ components of your toolset use the correct encoding: your browser request, the php engine, the mysql database management system, the connection and last not least the table definitions.

Comment: Set your database collation to utf8_unicode_ci